Subgroup of $\text{GL}_2$ fixing a line and the interpretation of linear transformation as matrices
I am trying to understand an argument from an abstract algebra lecture video from Benedict Gross. The setup is, we're considering a subgroup of $\text{GL}_2 (\mathbb{R})$ which fixes the line $y = 0$ in the plane.
If we agreed that we're working relative to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, I agree that this would be the set of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix}$ where $ad \neq 0$. Gross seems to assume this in his analysis, because he argues that the first column of the matrix says what the transformation does to the first standard basis vector and the second column what it does to the second standard basis vector.
But, in $\text{GL}_2 (\mathbb{R})$, aren't we not choosing a basis until we write down an explicit isomorphism? My understanding is that, when regarded as matrices, these are "rectangular arrays" of numbers, which we can only interpret as encoding a linear transformation after choosing a basis. If we choose a different basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, then surely the matrix representative will change and may not look like the above.

There are differing conventions. Gross's perspective (which is fairly common) is that $m \times n$ matrices encode transformations from $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ with respect to the standard basis by default, and if a different interpretation is intended then one can specify a vector space and basis.

(in the same evain as the comment by Ben Grossmann) In such a case, it is assumed implicitly that the underlying basis is the "canonical" basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$, i.e., ${\binom{1}{0},\binom{0}{1}}$
